# Mojo::DOM shortcut to get absolute url for a resource?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

When parsing a webpage with [`Mojo::DOM`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM) (or any other framework), it's fairly common to be pulling a resource address that could be either relative or absolute.  Is there a shortcut method to translate such a resource address to an absolute URL?

The following [`mojo`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Mojolicious/script/mojo) command pulls all the stylesheets on mojolicio.us:

```
$ mojo get http://mojolicio.us "link[rel=stylesheet]" attr href
/mojo/prettify/prettify-mojo-light.css
/css/index.css
```

And the following script does the same, but also uses [`URI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI) to translate the resource into an absolute URL.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Mojo::UserAgent;
use URI;

my $url = 'http://mojolicio.us';

my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
my $dom = $ua->get($url)->res->dom;

for my $csshref ($dom->find('link[rel=stylesheet]')->attr('href')->each) {
    my $cssurl = URI->new($csshref)->abs($url);
    print "$cssurl\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
http://mojolicio.us/mojo/prettify/prettify-mojo-light.css
http://mojolicio.us/css/index.css
```

Obviously, a relative URL in this context should be made absolute using the URL that loaded DOM.  However, I don't know of a way to get a resource absolute URL except for coding it myself.

There is [`Mojo::URL #to_abs`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::URL#to_abs) in `Mojolicious`.  However, I don't know if that would integrate in some way with `Mojo::DOM`, and by itself would take more code than `URI`.

My ideal solution would be if something like the following were possible from both a script and command line, but looking for any related insights into using Mojo for parsing:

```
mojo get http://mojolicio.us "link[rel=stylesheet]" attr href to_abs
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you think it would take more code to use `Mojo::URL`? In the following example I get the actual request URL from the transaction (there might have been redirects, which I've allowed) which I have called `$base`.

Then since `$base` is an instance of `Mojo::URL` I can create a new instance with `$base->new`. Of course if that seems to magical, you can replace it with `Mojo::URL->new`.

```
use Mojo::Base -strict;
use Mojo::UserAgent;

my $url = 'http://mojolicio.us';

my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new->max_redirects(10);
my $tx = $ua->get($url);
my $base = $tx->req->url;

$tx->res
  ->dom
  ->find('link[rel=stylesheet]')
  ->map(sub{$base->new($_->{href})->to_abs($base)})
  ->each(sub{say});
```